# Regular expression between 2 specific integers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for some pattern matching that will match values to a specific pattern range. The range is time based and looks like:

```
start_time = 162950
end_time = 162959
```

So any integer greater than or equal `162950` or less than or equal to `162959` would match to the pattern. Would something like the following work ?

```
import re
`PATTERN = re.compile("("+start_time+"[0-9]{0}|"+end_time+")$")`
```

If not, what do I need to do to match values inside the above range?

Comment: searching for items in a range of numbers is not something regex is good for. Instead, why not do it in two steps? Get all start/end times, and then filter out the ones that are not in a range.

Comment: seems like a simple if statement would work here.